# Selenium Webdriver : sometimes sends keys to wrong field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please refer to below code
Here I am trying to automate a report from Jira.

Steps:

```
1) Load Jira homepage
2) Wait for page to load
3) Add username to username field
4) Add password to password field
5) ...
```

While doing the 4th step, sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it adds password to username field itself, and leaves the password field blank.

Please help me identify the issue.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    // jiraHomePage = home page url (string)
            driver.get(jiraHomePage);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gadget-0"))); 
            driver.switchTo().frame("gadget-0");

            WebElement userNameField = driver.findElement(By
                    .id("login-form-username"));
            userNameField.sendKeys(username);
            WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By
                    .id("login-form-password"));
// this sometimes sends keys to username field instead of password field
            passwordField.sendKeys(password);
            WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
            loginButton.click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gadget-10002-title"))); 
            // source is page of report which I want to go to after login
            driver.get(source);

            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(driver.getPageSource()));
            Reporter.createReport(is,args[0]);
             driver.close();
        }
```

Comment: Did you try waiting for a second after entering the username?

Comment: click and clear than use send keys by using wait time.

Comment: I have not tried any of the above. I was with the lines: I have the element, sending keys to the element should send them to the element whatever happens. I guess, that is not how it works. let me try and get back

Comment: It worked. but I am not happy... thats a workaround :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In such a situation good to have some wait between user name and password. i hope

```
 Thread.sleep(2000);
```

helps better here.

Thanks

Comment: It worked. But please let me know why and how did it work?

Comment: Hi, i hope it is sync issue. as know, selenium executes very fast which may leads like this issues. if i used waits here, as element is may available so execution does not stopped for a while. so  Thread.sleep(2000); helps me in these situations to me a lot..